# Google Maps v2 dialog box popup on long press to select different marker types/ possible?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

Afternoon all, 
I have been wrestling with the Google Maps v2 API and cant seem to find a way to do this but here is a breakdown of essentially i would like. it has 2 version which could be possible used.

preferred actions. 
user does long press on area of map to be "tagged", a dialog(infowindow?) pops up and user selects type of marker to use from A,B,C or D. after selection the marker is plopped on the map and is then draggable if it is in wrong location.

backup method. 
a docking bar is on top of the screen with the map shown full screen, which has 4 icons. user drags icon from docking bar onto map and releases to plop the marker down. single tap then opens new activity.

are any of these possible? if so would you be kind enough to point me to a tut or show me an example?

thanks guys,

I already have google maps v2 working well with my location icon working as well as single draggable marker.

thanks again